# Having some serious trouble with novice "Hangman" program in Java

Tags: java

So this is my program, but when I run it the results are incorrect. For example, if the computer selects 'this' to be the word for the game, and 't' is entered, it is marked as wrong while other letters are marked as correct. Obviously something here is wrong, but for the life of my I cannot figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Hangman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //set words to array
        String[] words = {"write", "this", "that", "blue", "school", "table"};

        //initialize vars
        int tryLeft = 6;                //user gets 6 wrong guesses
        int guessTot = 0;               //initializes user guess counter
        boolean fin = false;            //fin controls do-while loop; stands for "finished?"
        String guessChar;               //use if user enters only 1 letter
        String guessed = "";            //contains all previous guesses
        StringBuffer asterisk;          //StringBuffer allows strings to be mutable; ast = asterisks in the word to display

        //initialize scanner
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = randomWord(words);
        //while user has not correctly guessed word, and has not lost the game, do this:
        do {
            //call randomWord method

            //**System.out.println(word);;

            //call asterisk method, wordAsAst
            asterisk = wordAsAst(word);
            //**System.out.println(asterisk);

            System.out.println("Your word is: " + word);
            System.out.println("Enter a letter in the word: ");
            guessChar = userInput.next();

            if(guessChar.length() == 1) {           //checking that user entered only 1 character
                guessed = guessed + guessChar;
                if (word.indexOf(guessChar) == 0) {     //if guessChar is not present in the word...
                    tryLeft = tryLeft - 1;                      //remove one try
                    System.out.println("Incorrect guess");
                }

            else {                                  //if guessChar is present in teh word...
                checkWord(asterisk, word, guessChar);
                System.out.println("Good guess!");
            }
            if(tryLeft == 0) {
                System.out.println("You have run out of tries. Sorry!");
                fin = true;
            }
            if(word.equals(asterisk.toString())) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations, you've won!");
                fin = true;
            }

            }   
        }while(!fin);
    }
    public static String randomWord(String[] words) {
        int indWords = new Random().nextInt(words.length);
        String randWord = (words[indWords]);
        return randWord;

    }
    public static StringBuffer wordAsAst(String word) {
        StringBuffer asterisks = new StringBuffer(word.length());
        for (int i = 0; i<=word.length(); i++) {
            asterisks.append("*");}
        return asterisks;
        }

    public static StringBuffer checkWord(StringBuffer asterisk, String word, String guessChar) {
        for(int j = 0; j<word.length(); j++) {
            if(word.charAt(j) == guessChar.charAt(0)){
                asterisk.setCharAt(j, guessChar.charAt(0)); 
            }
        }
        return asterisk;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Now's a perfect time to learn how to use your IDE's debugger.

Comment: `word.indexOf(guessChar) == 0` means the letter was found at index `0`. You actually want to check for `-1`, which means it was not found.

Comment: ...or simply use `if (word.contains(guessChar))`

Comment: Thanks all, definitely working in the right direction now! While it does recognize that a letter either is or is not in the word, something is wrong with my StringBuffer wordAsAst method, not sure what it is but I will keep plugging through! Any help on this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The line `if (word.indexOf(guessChar) == 0) {`looks very suspicious to me. In Java, the location of elements in a String (also arrays and Lists) go from 0 to `n`. Your if statement is asking if the location of guessChar in word is at 0, i.e. the first place

```
t h i s
0 1 2 3
```

t is indeed at location 0 in the word "this". Instead of checking at the first location, use -1 to check that the guessChar is not in word.

You can also use the method String.contains(String), which would look like:
`if (word.contains(guessChar)) {`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is at line 36

```
if (word.indexOf(guessChar) == 0) {     //if guessChar is not present in the word...
```

Java's `indexOf` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) returns:

> the index of the first occurrence of the character in the character sequence represented by this object, or -1 if the character does not occur.

If you start guessing `t` for your first guess (with the word being `this`) your program will output `0` because `t` has the index 0 in the word `this`.

Since `indexOf` returns -1 if the character does not occur, you should change this line to:

```
if (word.indexOf(guessChar) == -1) {     //if guessChar is not present in the word...
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
word.indexOf(guessChar) == 0
```

to this:

```
word.indexOf(guessChar) == -1
```

Answer (score 0):

at the following line (n. 36) you check the first char of the string:

```
if (word.indexOf(guessChar) == 0)
```

Change to

```
if (word.indexOf(guessChar) == -1)
```